# tinymce и динамическое добавление textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как мне заставить редактор tinymce добавляться к динамическим textarea ?
Например. Добавляю я textarea по кнопке

```
 $('#add').click(function() {
    $('<textarea id="'+i+'" name="option[]"></textarea>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#ftable');        
    i++;    
});
```

Пробовал вызывать tinymce.init сразу же после добавления textarea - срабатывает через раз (добавил например 4 textarea, а редактор присвоился только к 2-м - через 1).

Вот тут тестовый вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/morrowinds/z9fhqfx6/1/

А здесь полурабочий вариант, который я описал уже - https://jsfiddle.net/morrowinds/z9fhqfx6/2/

Comment: ну так полностью код опубликуйте

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/morrowinds/z9fhqfx6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var id = 'textarea' + i++;
  $('<textarea id="'+id+'" name="option[]"></textarea>').appendTo('#textareas');
  tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, id);
```